# SonarQube warning: A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getBody()" can return null

Tags: java, sonarqube

```java
ResponseEntity<CommonResponseDTO> commonResponseDto = testClient.getCategoryById(sampleEntity.getCategoryId());   

if(Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto) && Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto.getBody()) && Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto.getBody().getName())){

SuperDataDto superDataCategoryDto =  SuperDataDto.builder().id(sampleEntity.getCategoryId()).name(commonResponseDto.getBody().getName()).build();
```

In the above code SonarQube complains that

```
A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getBody()" can return null. on 

.name(commonResponseDto.getBody().getName())
```

I am even checking the `nonNull` for `commonResponseDto.getBody().getName())`.  Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is the getBody() reading a non-final attribute ? Maybe sonarQube thinks the result of getBody() can change between the calls...

Comment: Maybe try literally doing `!= null` instead.

Comment: Not what you are asking for, but those null checks are quite cumbersome. Why don't you return `Optional<CommonResponseDTO>`, and then - `commonResponseDto.map(CommonResponseDTO::getBody).map(Body::getName).orElse(null)` to get the name?

Comment: @Chaosfire the advantage of that would also be that each call is issued only once and thus it can not become null the second time

Comment: @Chaosfire can you please edit  my code ?

Comment: It means that you should use variables to store to the result of the calls and refer to that value ie `var body = commonResponseDto.getBody(); var name = body.getName();` and then you do your checks on these variables

Comment: Question - is there also a similar complaint about the *second* getBody call from your example ? The *'Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto.getBody().getName())'* to be exact...

Comment: @Mandrek Not really, that would completely change your question. It was just a suggestion to make the code more readable, not for a fix (it may fix the sonar issue, or may not). Anyway the idea was to change the return type of `testClient.getCategoryById` to `Optional<ResponseEntity<CommonResponseDTO>>` and then to get the name like this - `commonResponseDto.map(ResponseEntity::getBody).map(CommonResponseDTO::getName).orElse(null)`. You may default to some other value, not null, if this is not what you need.

Comment: @Chaosfire ... or just use Optional.ofNullable(....) to wrap the returned result

Comment: @MBobrik Yes, but this is using optional to hide null checks, which is considered bad practice. Since the returned response entity itself can be null, it's best to return an optional from his method to indicate the possibility of null result.

Comment: @Chaosfire Yes, it is of course better to return optional - provided one *can* change the code of the getCategoryById - if not, one has to Optional.ofNullable

Comment: @MBobrik In this case it would be better to just save the result in a variable, instead of using a bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube is right.

```
if(Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto)
  && Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto.getBody())
  && Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto.getBody().getName())) {
SuperDataDto superDataCategoryDto =  SuperDataDto.builder().id(sampleEntity.getCategoryId()).name(commonResponseDto.getBody().getName()).build();
```

Makes no guarantee about the return value of `getBody()` of consecutive calls. Here's an implementation that would easily make your condition throw:

```
private int calls = 0;

public Body getBody() {
  ++calls;
  if (calls % 2 == 0) return null;
  return new Body(...);
}
```

The first check is non-null, calling it a second time will return null and your code throws an exception. Don't rely on methods to return the same reference from multiple calls, if you require a single value, be explicit about it and store it in a local variable:

```
if (Objects.nonNull(commonResponseDto)) {
  final CommonResponseDTO body = commonResponseDto.getBody();
  if (Objects.nonNull(body)) {
    final String name = body.getName();
    if (Objects.nonNull(name)) {
      SuperDataDto superDataCategoryDto = SuperDataDto.builder()
          .id(sampleEntity.getCategoryId())
          .name(name)
          .build();
```

Note that `Objects#nonNull` is mainly intended to be used as a method reference in lambda expressions and your code could be clearer if you simply wrote `obj != null`.

But this becomes ugly quickly. You can increase the clarity of your code by moving it to a small helper function:

```
private static String nameOfResponse(
    final ResponseEntity<CommonResponseDTO> response) {
  if (response == null) return null;
  final CommonResponseDTO body = commonResponseDto.getBody(); 
  if (body == null) return null;
  return body.getName();
}

// ...
final String name = nameOfResponse(commonResponseDto);
if (name != null) {
  final SuperDataDto superDataCategoryDto = SuperDataDto.builder()
      .id(sampleEntity.getCategoryId())
      .name(name)
      .build();
}
```

An alternative with a little bit of overhead is wrapping your object in an `Optional` and then transforming this optional value:

```
Optional.ofNullable(commonResponseDto)
    .map(CommonResponseDTO::getBody)
    .map(Body::getName())
    .ifPresent(name -> {
      SuperDataDto superDataCategoryDto = SuperDataDto.builder()
          .id(sampleEntity.getCategoryId())
          .name(name)
          .build();
    });
```

Comment: Look at the code. Body the *ResponseEntity.getBody()* returns is **final** ... also, sonarQube would then already complain at the second call of getBody(), not only the third. Seems to be a sonarQube problem. Yes, ultimately it would be better to refactor the code as you (and other commenters before you) suggested. But that does not answer the question.

Comment: Your optional example suffers from 2 problems - 1. It is used explicitly to hide null checks, and I suspect that sonar may complain about this and 2. The way it is written it will result in a 2nd invocation of `getBody` inside the body of the if statement, which is exactly what you advise against in the first part of your answer.

Comment: @MBobrik This is an implementation detail, you can't count on it staying this way forever. There are many more ways to implement this method, while keeping it true to the contract.

Comment: @MBobrik I'm not sure what is final? The question does not show the code of `ResponseBody`, so I have to assume that it is [`org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<T>`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-web/latest/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html). Neither the class, nor the method is final, so a derived class can easily override the method with an implementation that sometimes returns null (e.g. on second access). The type does not guarantee that `getBody()` returns the same value or reference on repeated calls. SonarQube can only do static code analysis.

Comment: @Chaosfire thanks, yes, that is an issue, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @knittl, yes, you are right with the possibility of overriding the method in a derived class. Never mind, in the default implementation it just returns a final attribute and thus can't return something different.  And also, the sonarQube is inconsistent here - doesn't report the second call but does the third, so at least one of those has to be wrong.

Comment: @MBobrik not sure what is inconsistent here. Only `commonResponseDto.getBody().getName()` could throw, anything before doesn't access potentially-null values. Everything after isn't analyzed, because the exception would have occured earlier. SonarQube will always only show the first violation and ignore any follow-up issues.

Comment: @knittl ```commonResponseDto.getBody().getName()``` occurs twice in the example - and it is reported the *second* time as parameter of the ```.name(...)```, but not the first time, which is in the *if* as the next condition ```&& Objects.nonNull(...)```. If it were reported the first time, and not the second time, it would be as you said. But like this ...

Comment: @MBobrik oh, you are right. Well, SonarQube is not perfect, and the code is still broken :) Perhaps SonarQube ignores the first occurence, because it is inside a null check? I can only guess …